# auto scroll al seleccionar elemento LI activo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

tengo un input que funciona como buscador y cuando dígito muestra una ul dinámica con la lista de coincidencias y funciona.

Este es el input:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es el Ul:

Después que se genera la lista, se selecciona el primer item de la lista (como imagen), ademas se debe de usar las teclas de flecha (arriba y abajo) para seleccionar uno de los elementos el cual tiene el siguiente codigo:

```
    var h = 0;
    $("#txtDepProv").keyup(function (e) {
           if (e.keyCode == 38) {                 
            h--;
            if (h >= $("li").length) {
                h = -1;
                return;
            }
            $("#listResultadoDepProv>li").removeClass("itemliactive");
            $("#listResultadoDepProv>li").eq(h).addClass("itemliactive");                
            return;
        };
        if (e.keyCode == 40) {                                    
            h++;
            if (h > $("li").length) {//                    
                console.log($("li").length);
                h = 1;                    
                return;
                }
            $("#listResultadoDepProv>li").removeClass("itemliactive");
            $("#listResultadoDepProv>li").eq(h).addClass("itemliactive")                          
            return;
        };            
        h=0;
```

}
lo que aun no logro es: que al momento que se deslice hacia arriba o abajo, el scroll tambien lo haga, es decir el scroll tiene que seguir al item seleccionado.

Answer (score 0):

prueba el siguiente codigo JQuery:

```
//coloca un id a tu ul, por ejemplo id="lista"
$("#lista li").keyup(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38: //flecha arriba
            $(this).prev().focus();
            break;
        case 40: //flecha abajo
            $(this).next().focus();
            break;
    }
});
//crea una funcion a tu input y llamala cuando presiones una tecla
function selectFirst(){
    $("#lista li").first().focus(); //selecciona el primer elemento de la lista.
}
```

Comment: Hola John agregue mas detalle a la pregunta ps no logro probar con el codigo que dejaste. Gracias

Comment: Hola Nelson, te dejo este enlace http://jsfiddle.net/squeral/4jf0n2ff/ con algo muy parecido a lo que quieres lograr. Lo que interesa para este caso es la parte del scrollTop. Saludos